# VBA rename files in folder keeping the right order

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, sequence, rename

I've found this code that renames all the files into a specific folder.

```
Const FolderLoc = "C:\Users\chf000\Desktop\AAA\"
Dim x As Long
x = 1
Dim s As String
s = Dir(FolderLoc & "*.*")
Do While s <> ""
       Name FolderLoc & s As FolderLoc & "ANIMATIC-" & x & ".png"
    s = Dir()
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

It works, but I've got an issue during the renaming. Basically, I've got a png's sequence into the folder, like this: SHOT001_00.png and SHOT001_01.png and so one.
the sequence has more than 100 frames.
the script changes the name from SHOT001_00.png to ANIMATIC-0.png and so one.
When I run the script, the files are renamed in the wrong order.
For example, the file named ANIMATIC-12.png contains the image that belongs to frame 101.
I guess is a problem of how the script sort the files in the folder, is sorting in a sort of alphabetical order, rather than numerical order.
Does anyone know how can I edit the script in order to rename and keep the correct order?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first put all the names in an array and then rename them from that list.
I use this code to get the file list into an array:

```
Private Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
'   Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'   If no matching files are found, it returns False

    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim FileName As String

    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

    FileCount = 0
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
    If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

    'Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
    Exit Function

    '   Error handler
NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function
```